# goto equivalent for php version < 5.3.0?

Tags: php, goto

I need to use the goto operator in my code as I can't seem to think of a way around it. However the problem is my host only has PHP version 5.2.17 installed.

Any ideas?

Below is my code:

```
if ($ready !=="y")
{
    $check=mysql_query("SELECT `inserted` FROM `team`");
    $numrows  = mysql_num_rows($check);  

    $i="0";

    while ($i<$numrows && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check))
    {

        $array[$i] = $row['inserted'];
        $i++;

    }
    if (in_array("n", $array)) 
    {

        goto skip;

    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("

            UPDATE game SET ready='y'

        ");
    }

}

skip:
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `goto`?  More importantly, I was surprised to see this **added** in PHP 5.3 instead of removed.  Horrifying.

Comment: "I need to use the goto operator in my code" implies bad design.

Comment: "I need to use the goto operator in my code as I can't seem to think of a way around it." Impossible

Comment: I realize this but I can't figure out a way around this

Comment: @user1064028, You realize that you could just get rid of goto and that label and it would work the same right?

Comment: I bet if you posted the PHP 5.3 code you need to eliminate the goto from you'd get lots of useful suggestions... Just saying.... Without seeing the logic flow it's hard to answer.

Comment: I'm normally against bashing code.. but in this case the PHP community needs to stand against this kind of usage of the `goto` operator. PHP already has a bad rep :(

Comment: Didnt know goto was a sensitive subject :/

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD Comic](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few anti-patterns in your code.  Let's clean it up.  I'll explain what's been changed in a jiffy.

```
if($ready !== "y") {
    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT inserted FROM team WHERE inserted = 'n'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sth) > 0) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE game SET ready = 'y'");
    }
}
```

First things first: There is no need to perform a query, fetch *all* of the results, then loop through those results (`in_array`) looking for a specific value.  Let the database do that for you by expressly looking only for rows where `inserted` is the string literal `"n"`.

Because we know that we're only getting `"n"` records back, we just need to check if there are any results.  If so, run the query.  If there are no `"n"` records, the `UPDATE` isn't run.

If you need to know that the `UPDATE` ran, add a check for it:

```
$ran_update = false;
if($ready !== "y") {
    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT inserted FROM team WHERE inserted = 'n'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sth) > 0) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE game SET ready = 'y'");
        $ran_update = true;
    }
}
if($ran_update) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Charles I am new to programming, and trying to learn several languages for in a short space of time for a school project gets me quite flustered at times. I appreciate the help.

Comment: It's never easy learning to program, and never ever easy learning how to program in multiple languages at once.  Good luck!  Once you're no longer stressed for time, consider reviewing all of the code you've written and finding ways to make it more concise and express your actual intent better.  This is one of the steps in [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).  While doing so, you should also seriously consider switching to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of using the horrifyingly prehistoric `mysql_` family of functions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the correct control word to break from the loop:

```
if ($ready !=="y")
{
    $check=mysql_query("SELECT `inserted` FROM `team`");
    $numrows  = mysql_num_rows($check);  

    $i="0";


    while ($i<$numrows && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check))
    {


    $array[$i] = $row['inserted'];
    $i++;

    }
    if (in_array("n", $array)) 
    {

        break;

    }
    else
    {
    mysql_query("

    UPDATE game SET ready='y'

    ");
    }

}
```

The [break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) keyword will do exactly what you want: End the execution of the while loop. Never ever ever use a goto!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can't use `break`,  because that `break` in your post is not within the `while` loop.

Comment: @nickb Consider yourself corrected :) See the first example listed in the link http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: But the first example has the `break` statement inside the `while` loop. In your post, the `break` statement is outside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As a direct response to the title of this post:

```
do{

  if (!$condition){
    break;
  }

  // Code called if conditions above are met

}while(0);

//Code always called
```

In some circumstances, this, or a goto, can make for very tidy and readable code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could use a `break` to exit your initial loop. Second, if you need to test for anything, set a variable (must be global not local) as a flag or indicator before calling `break`, then do a conditional test statement where your `skip` line is to perform any additional steps you need.